# Load json from text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following hard coded json,

```
var dataLocality = [
    { "label": "Arwen" },
    { "label": "Bilbo Baggins" },
    { "label": "Boromir" },
    { "label": "Frodo Baggins" },
    { "label": "Peregrin Pippin Took" },
    { "label": "Samwise Gamgee" }
];
```

Which I use to populate an autocomplete textbox with the following script,

```
$(function () {
    $("#locality").autocomplete(
    {
        source: dataLocality
    })
});
```

I now have a text file that is dynamically updated via my app named dataLocality.text which i'm able to load and view in an alert box with this code,

```
function codeAddress() {
    jQuery.get('http://localhost/project/jSonDocs/dataWhat.txt', function (data) {
        var dataLocality = data;
        alert(dataLocality);
    });
}
window.onload = codeAddress;
```

But I can't seem to work out how to get the data from `var dataLocality` to `source: dataLocality`

The data in my text doc looks like this,

```
[
    { "label": "Arwen" },
    { "label": "Bilbo Baggins" },
    { "label": "Boromir" },
    { "label": "Frodo Baggins" },
    { "label": "Peregrin Pippin Took" },
    { "label": "Samwise Gamgee" }
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using the jQueryUI autocomplete method, you can provide the URL of the JSON to the `source` method and it will retrieve it for you automatically. Try this:

```
$("#locality").autocomplete({
    source: 'http://localhost/project/jSonDocs/dataWhat.txt'
});
```

If you still prefer to retrieve the JSON manually (if you need to change the source after initialisation for example) then you can achieve it like this:

```
function codeAddress() {
    jQuery.get('http://localhost/project/jSonDocs/dataWhat.txt', function (data) {
        $('#locality').autocomplete('option', 'source', data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rory. Thanks for that, both great examples and I now have my autocomplete working perfectly. Cheers, Mike.